# d3.Js - How to set custom("string") values to `y-Axis` - ticks

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In my bar chart, I have the left `y` axis values as `string` formats, how to set those values to the `xAxis` - ticks?

here is my code : please see in comments for details

```
window.onload = function(){

    var margin = { left:30, top:30, right:30, bottom:30 },
      width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      totalWidth = width + margin.left + margin.right,
      totalHeight = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

    var data =  [5,20,80,120,35,90,340, 145, 601, 11, 67, 810 ];
    var yData = [2012,2013,2014,2015,2016];
    //how to set aData to yAxis?
    var aData = ['0','$50M','$1B','$1.5B','$2B', '$2.5B','$3B'];

  var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

  var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
  x.domain(yData.map(function(d) { return d; }));

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom");
  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickFormat(function(d){
    return d; //i required to set from aData 
  }).orient("left").ticks(5);

  var svg = d3.select('#container').append('svg').attr({width:totalWidth,height:totalHeight});
  var graphMargin = "translate(" + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')';

  var playBoard = svg.append('g').attr("transform", graphMargin);

  playBoard.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height+1) + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  playBoard.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, which I used to render a bar chart. It plots with time stamp along x-axis and value along y-axis.

```
function RenderLineChart(data) {
        // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
        var margin = { top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
            width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = 250 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // Parse the date / time
        var parseTime = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;

        // Set the ranges
        var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

        // Define the axes
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
            .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
            .orient("left").ticks(5);

        // Define the line
        var valueline = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.Timestamp); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.Value); });

        // Adds the svg canvas
        var svg = d3.select("#d3Graph")
            .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
                .attr("transform",
                      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        data.forEach(function (d) {
            d.Timestamp = parseTime(d.Timestamp);
            d.Value = +d.Value;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) { return d.Timestamp; }));
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) { return d.Value; })]);

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline(data));

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);
    }
```

The below code defines the axes.

```
 // Define the line
        var valueline = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return x(d.Timestamp); })
            .y(function (d) { return y(d.Value); });
```